# JFreeChart: bar overlaps y-axis

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am using JFreeChart to generate bar charts. Everything is working find, but I have one very minor issue: the left side of the bar is overlapping the y-axis. I would prefer to have the bars sticking (but not overlapping) to the axis. If my description is unclear: everything would be perfect if the bars move 1 pixel to the right.

At first I thought the bar's stroke was the problem, but disabling the stroke gives the same problem.

**Edit**: The image is zoomed in at the problem area. The blue areas are the bars, and I would like the axis (the gray line) to be drawn on top, and not below.

[image]

Comment: Could you please add an example image?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a CategoryPlot, so you should have a CategoryDomain as the x-axis (Numeric as y)  as the plot area so you'll need to set the margins (as a percent of axis) for the CategoryDomain that you've defined as the x-axis. I used this feature in a CombinedRangeCategoryPlot something like this:

```
    CombinedRangeCategoryPlot plot = new CombinedRangeCategoryPlot(numberAxis);
    CategoryAxis domain = new CategoryAxis();
    domain.setLowerMargin(0.2);
    domain.setUpperMargin(0.2);
    plot.add(new CategoryPlot(data, domain, null, renderer));
```

see documentation: http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/CategoryAxis.html#setUpperMargin(double)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may want to invoke [`setBase()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/BarRenderer.html#setBase%28double%29) on your `BarRenderer`. You'll probably have to adjust the value empirically.

```
BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
renderer.setBase(0.01);
```